# Ubuntu unzip error: sysmalloc assertion failed

Tags: ubuntu, zip, glibc

I'm trying to unzip a multipart zip file (that I had originally zipped in Windows using WinRAR). The file consists of 4 parts: `me.zip` and `me.z01`, `me.z02`, `me.z03` and `me.z04`.

The command I'm using to do the unzip in Ubuntu is: `zip -FF me.zip --out me-full.zip`

When I run this command, it starts listing a bunch of files ... eventually failing with the following message:

```
copying: me/wpuqps psupthr/pswpuqps/tvpezps psbrpuy/pswdwqr wpsqupj
pspustphy.docx zip: malloc.c:2373: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top ==
(((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -
__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof
(struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) &
~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) &&
((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

zip error: Interrupted (aborting)
```

Can I make it skip this error and continue extracting the remainig files? How can I recover the operation and continue to salvage the other (presumably uncorrupted) files?

Comment: It's not caused by the zip file. If you can produce a similar file without your important data (yes, I mean only garbage) that triggers the same behavior, it will be a good idea to tell the Ubuntu guys about this bug. The Ubuntu guys will check if it's a Ubuntu libc `malloc` bug, a `unzip` bug or some mistakes they made making the `unzip` software package.

Comment: For a workaround, try unpacking it with something else, e.g. `bsdtar` and `p7zip` stuffs. Or even wine WinRAR.

Comment: Running it under `gdb` and getting a `bt` might be handy for debugging.

Comment: @thrig The problem is `malloc` found something wrong. Can be some writes to not yet allocated spaces (e.g. array index out-of-bound) in `unzip`, and clobbering some markers for block size left by `malloc`. Anyway he should write a bug report first… (`unzip` has done such before: https://www.debian.org/security/2015/dsa-3152) Additionally, Ubuntu often release binaries with debug symbols separated so `gdb` won't really give anything useful……

Comment: Please add information on your Ubuntu version and `unzip` version. If you find out that `unzip` is a version released before Feb 2015, you should definitely use `apt` stuffs to upgrade it and try.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur2e5.. I'm using the latest Ubuntu 15.04 I believe. I don't have access to the computer now so can't get the precise unzip version.

Comment: 15.04, then unlikely to have a Feb 2015 bug…